# how to get all global variable

Tags: php, function, global

instead of using $_POST['var'] I would like to get all globals by their name.

Also for example I have `<input type='text' name='surname'>`  When I submit the form I would like to use get('surname') instead of $_POST['surname'] so I tried to do a function but this one does not work

```
function get($var){
    $global = $GLOBALS["$var"] ;
    return $global;
}
```

I really do not understand why.

I return to me `notice: Undefined index: nom in C:\wamp\www\cyb.fr\lib_php\librairie.php on line 23`

anykind of help will be much appreciated

Comment: How is your function-based approach any better than the usual `$_POST` approach, other than saving a few characters? It's certainly not any faster to process.

Comment: ok I unserstand is there a wy I can get post ?

Comment: There is a way, the ONLY way: `$_POST['surname']`. Everything else is just a wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use below function:

```
function post_value($key=''){
if($key!='')    {
    if(!is_array($_POST[$key]))
            return trim($_POST[$key]);
        else
            return $_POST[$key];

}
else
    return;
}
```

Comment: This is probably the clunkiest solution to this non-problem; and of course it got accepted.

Answer (score 2):

why not

```
function get($var) {
  return $_POST[$var];
 }
```

?

Comment: it returns me the same mistake

Comment: the error say 'nom' not found but your example use 'surname' ...

Comment: A function called "`get`" to return POST body values... As if the default PHP nomenclature wasn't confusing enough already. ;-P Still the correct answer though.

Comment: @deceze I'm just implementing the OP function, not renaming it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Any request data like POST and GET are not registered as global variables unless you have the `register_globals` directive in php.ini turned on. I would bet to say that it is NOT turned on and it should NOT be turned on. Since PHP 4.x sometime it was defaulted to OFF.

**Alternative**

```
function get($variable) {
    return isset($_REQUEST[$variable]) 
        ? $_REQUEST[$variable] : null;
}
```